# Pandas: Reading in first x chunks or lines of large bz2 file using read_json

Tags: python, json, pandas, while-loop

Attempting to read in a bz2 file using pd.read_json

```
 i = 0
while i <3:
  i = i +1 
  df = pd.read_json("file.bz2",lines=True, chunksize = 100)
for c in chunks:
    print(c)
```

This doesn't stop at 3 chunks. How do i read in x amount of chunks or x amount of lines.

Comment: chucksize will get 100 lines for 3 times, which eventually result with 300 lines. Check out chuck usage from : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#line-delimited-json

Comment: Why do you want to read only part of the file?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes, i would only like to read part of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
chunks = pd.read_json("file.bz2",lines=True, chunksize = 100)
i = 0
chunk_list = []
for chunk in chunks:
    if i >= 3:
        break
    i += 1
    # do something with that chunk like this:
    result = pd.merge(chunk, merge_df)
    chunk_list.append(result)
 df = pd.concat(chunk_list)
```

Comment: If OP is asking this question because they either can’t or doesn’t want to load the entire thing, this answer doesn’t work, right?

Comment: he wants to stop after 3 chunks. i gave an example to that

Comment: I just checked the docs, turns out I was misremembering the details of `chunksize`... *facepalm*

Comment: @luigigi i noticed "result" is not defined. How would you approach appending each chunk?

Comment: @HarriS sorry. result should be a result from the chunk modifications. like a merge on an other df. i edit my answer

Comment: The loop with a counter could be replaced with [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). Call `pandas.concat()` on the result and you're done.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile i didn't know about that. thanks for the hint